# Best way for a multiple table query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to learn LINQ and have been playing around with some queries. The following LINQ queries are using the Northwind database. The following shows the fields being used (products that customers have ordered)

Customers (CustID, CompanyName)

Orders(OrderID, CustomerID)

OrderDetails(OrderID, ProductID)

Products(ProductiAD, ProductName)

Query Syntax:

```
from c in Customers
               join o in Orders on c.Custid equals o.Custid
               join od in OrderDetails on o.Orderid equals od.Orderid
               join p in Products on od.Productid equals p.Productid
               select new 
               {
                    Order = od.Orderid,
                    Company = c.Companyname,
                    Product = p.Productname
               };
```

Fluent Syntax:

```
Customers.Join(Orders, c=> c.CustomerID, o=> o.CustomerID, (c,o) => new {c, o} )
                   .Join(OrderDetails, co => co.o.OrderID, od => od.OrderID, (co, od) => new {co, od})
                   .Join(Products, cood => cood.od.ProductID, p => p.ProductID, (cood, p) => new {cood, p})
                   .Select (a => new
                   {
                        OrderNo = a.cood.co.o.OrderID,
                        Company = a.cood.co.c.CompanyName,
                        Product = a.p.ProductName

                   });
```

While these both work I suspect I am thinking too much in SQL rather than LINQ. I keep reading that there are better ways to join tables but I am unsure what the best way to do it would be with multiple tables. Can anyone show me more LINQ like ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in terms of SQL and not LINQ. I would say when you have **objects collection** and you want to fetch the data from that **LINQ** will be a great tool for it whereas joining of Tables **SQL** is still a better idea whereas LINQ extends the language by the addition of query expressions, which are akin to SQL statements, and can be used to conveniently extract and process data from arrays, enumerable classes, XML documents, relational databases, and third-party data sources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess it is more about me trying to understand the different way to do things in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've told EntityFramework about your database schema and relationships, you really should be able to write this:

```
Products.Select(p => {
    Product = p.ProductName,
    Company = p.OrderDetails.Order.Customer.CompanyName,
    OrderNo = p.OrderDetails.Order.OrderID
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about not EF? I have found posts saying to use SelectMany, but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = from s in db.Speakers
                     join
                         c in db.Conferences on s.ConferenceId equals c.ConferenceId 
                        where  c.ConferenceId == id 
                     select new
                     {
                         s.SpeakerName,
                         c.MeetingTitle,
                         c.ImgUrl,
                         c.Enddate,
                         c.StartDate,
                         c.Conferenceroom,
                         c.ConferenceId
                     };``
```